# My Minecraft server doesn't work if the lid on my laptop is closed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, macos

I have a Minecraft server set up on Mac OS X. Whenever the lid on my laptop is closed, the terminal says:

> Can't keep up! Did the system time change, or is the server overloaded?

The entire server then crashes and no one can play on my server until I wake my computer. What is going on? Can I fix the problem?

Comment: I don't know much about Macs, but I'm assuming the computer goes into sleep mode. You probably need to find a way to turn that off when the lid is closed.

Comment: "My programs don't work when my computer is closed" isn't a game-specific question, and an identical problem could happen to any other program. Hence, I'm flagging this for closure as off-topic.

Answer (score 11):

Apple laptops of that vintage sleep when the clamshell is closed, suspending any processes, including your Minecraft server.

[There are a few ways to keep Mac laptop from sleeping when you close the lid.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/is-there-any-way-to-set-a-macbook-pro-to-not-sleep-when-you-close-the-lid) However, note that the reason the default behaviour is to go to sleep is because the laptops are not engineered to properly deal with the heat of running programs while the lid is closed, so if you do use any of these hacks, be sure to keep a close eye on it to make sure Minecraft doesn't overheat it.

Comment: [This](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2412) may also be helpful with putting the display to sleep instead of the computer.